# Detecting if a method is declared in an interface in Java

Tags: java, reflection, methods

Help me make this method more solid:

```
 /**
  * Check if the method is declared in the interface.
  * Assumes the method was obtained from a concrete class that 
  * implements the interface, and return true if the method overrides
  * a method from the interface.
  */
 public static boolean isDeclaredInInterface(Method method, Class<?> interfaceClass) {
     for (Method methodInInterface : interfaceClass.getMethods())
     {
         if (methodInInterface.getName().equals(method.getName()))
             return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: You can have two methods with the same name but with different parameters.

Comment: Why?  What would that information buy for you?

Comment: Why do people always insist to know "the why" here ? :)

I want to expose these methods only from a Hessian servlet via HTTP-GET, and I want to filter non-relevant methods - filtering by the interface is exactly what I need.

Comment: because if they don't know the answer, the question must be wrong.

Comment: @ripper234, because they might be able to suggest easier solutions to the original problem.

Comment: The reason we wonder why is because on the surface it sounds a little backwards and your explanation leaves out details needed to make that not so.  For example, if you know the interface and you know your object implements that interface then why not only expose methods from the interface instead of from the concrete class?

Comment: All concrete classes expose public methods I'm not interested in (equals, hash, ...). Furthermore, the object is part of an object hierarchy, and its base classes expose many methods that I want to hide.

Comment: Sure, but something is introspecting that class to find the methods that you then pass to this utility function to see if it belongs to a particular interface.  I'm wondering why bother introspecting the concrete class if you only want methods from the interface... just introspect the interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
try {
    interfaceClass.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
    return true;
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use exceptions as part of your normal control logic.

Comment: @Anon, as a rule no, but if that is what the API gives you, then there you are. How do you determine if a String can be parsed into an Integer?

Comment: Haven't used Java in a while - C# provides `TryParse` for that purpose.

Comment: Need to catch SecurityException as well, although, in that case (access to package or method denied), I don't know whether you'd want to return true or false.  If access to package is denied, the method may or may not exist.  If access to method is denied, I'm pretty sure the method exists but you can't access it.

Comment: Yeah, I argued for a while on java.net for an Integer.isInt(String) method, but apparently I was a minority.

Comment: @shoover, the only way you could get the parameters the method requires is by having the relevant security. Sure a security manager could deny this method specifically, but is that worth defending against?

Comment: Security is not relevant in the context of my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid catching `NoSuchMethodException` from [Yashai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954983/150884):

```java
for (Method ifaceMethod : iface.getMethods()) {
    if (ifaceMethod.getName().equals(candidate.getName()) &&
            Arrays.equals(ifaceMethod.getParameterTypes(), candidate.getParameterTypes())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start:

Replace:

```
for (Method methodInInterface : interfaceClass.getMethods())
 {
     if (methodInInterface.getName().equals(method.getName()))
         return true;
 }
```

with:

```
for (Method methodInInterface : interfaceClass.getMethods()) {
     if (methodInInterface.getName().equals(method.getName())) {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

To make your method more robust, you probably also want to check if [`Class#isInterface()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) returns `true` for the given class and throw `IllegalArgumentException` otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

See [Method#getDeclaringClass()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass()), then just compare Class objects with the expected interface(s).

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I'd suggest to reread the question and all answers then.

Comment: when you call getDeclaringClass() on method whicd defined inside interfaces , the result will be the implementaion class . so this won't work at all.